# UIBarButton Tappable area is too much

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, ios5, uibarbuttonitem

I am having a UIBarButtonItem which i added from NIB. and its width is 33. But that BarButton tapable area is too much. i.e. outside width also we can tap on that button. How to reduce tappable area equal to UIBarButton Width.
Thanks In Advance.

Comment: put your code my frnd.

Comment: if you have assigned some image to that button then remove it n check its 'tappable area' ...

Comment: i just added uibarbutton from nib and given image. nothing else i did. but before that button i added Flexible space

Comment: @NitinGohel, coding is not a pblm here, OP added the UIBarButton to xib

Answer (score 4, accepted):

UIBarButtonItem by default have an overlay on it.  It is not possible to restrict that extra tappable area using the standard UIBarButtonItem.  Better way is to use a normal button which is going to looks like a UIBarButtonItem.

Comment: Thanks Bhanu. Whatever u told thats right but for that i needed designer and today i dont have designer with me, so for quick fix i added 1 hidden UIBarButtonItem next to my UIBarButtonItem button, using that fix my issue. I knw its not perfect solution but for nw that only i can do.

Answer (score 1):

It's by default. U can't reduce the tappable area of UIBarButton.

But I always used to solve this by adding an UIButton with custom image of UIBarButton to the UIView and change the x,y co-ordinates of that UIButton to the frame of UIBarButton and care to take the UIButton should be in the subview of UIView not in the tabbar.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

1. Take object of UIView
2. Create and add UIButton objects in that UIView Object
3. set that UIView object as titleview of navigation item.

[self.navigationController.navigationItem setTitleView:viewobj];